# Mysql: link records with special characters to the very first alphabet after the special characters and retrive

Tags: mysql, database, select, special-characters

```
create table temp_surnames( last_name varchar(100) not null primary key, create_date datetime not null);

insert into temp_surnames (last_name) values('$$moses’);
insert into temp_surnames (last_name) values(‘\'moses’);
insert into temp_surnames (last_name) values('moses’);
insert into temp_surnames (last_name) values(‘ammoses');
```

I want to retreive every record except 'ammoses'. Basically every record that starts with `m%`, but if i use `'%m%'` all are returned. Please recommend.

Comment: use a regex instead, and exclude/include whatever prefix chars you do want to allow. doing this with `like` and wildcards would be very inefficient.

Comment: @MarcB: Thank you. Yes regex works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple regular expression would be something like:

```
where last_name regexp '^[^[:alpha:]]*m'
```

Comment: That works! Thank you! I do have an additional following question : How do use the above in: SELECT last_name
FROM temp_surnames 
        WHERE last_name CONCAT(last_name, '%')
ORDER BY last_name

Comment: I'm not sure what your query is trying to do, but this `where` condition can just be the `where` clause in your query.